# Handling a database with more coordinate points than I need to be returned

Tags: postgis, postgresql, database

I have a database with millions of coordinate points and I need to select a subset of them to create a heat map based on a bounding box.  There are so many points that it's hurting performance on my front end (Leaflet).  What are the best practices to thin out the returned points?  I was thinking returning the first 500 or so that match the bounding box query, but was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: You might experiment with MultiPoints, since they can return *all* vertices much faster than simple Point geometries. You just need to find an appropriate grid size by which to cluster your data. I was able to render hundreds of thousands of points (out of hundreds of millions) across a study area in 200-250 milliseconds, but there's a point of diminishing returns in vertices per feature to scale by trial.

Comment: unless your points change very often why not calculate the heat map once and store it instead

Answer (score 3):

The features in the table are often stored in some spatial order, like from west to east and north to south. The first 500 points may all come from one corner of the bounding box. If you are using PostGIS I would recommend to try `tablesample` https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TABLESAMPLE_Implementation.